# unary operator expected in shell script when comparing null value with string

Tags: shell

I have two variables

```
var=""
var1=abcd
```

Here is my shell script code

```
if [ $var == $var1 ]; then
  do something
else
  do something
fi
```

If I run this code it will prompt a warning

```
[: ==: unary operator expected
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: To format code in a post, just highlight it and click the "{}" icon (or indent it by 4 spaces). Your code was marked with `>` (which denotes quoted text, not formatted code) and unnecessary `<br>` tags. I fixed it.

Comment: There are numerous other questions on StackOverflow dealing with the need to quote variables in case they are unset or null-valued.

Comment: Just a reminder: To indicate that an answer solved your problem, you can click the green arrow to "accept" it. Which answer to accept, and whether to accept an answer at all, is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Since the value of `$var` is the empty string, this:

```
if [ $var == $var1 ]; then
```

expands to this:

```
if [ == abcd ]; then
```

which is a syntax error.

You need to quote the arguments:

```
if [ "$var" == "$var1" ]; then
```

You can also use `=` rather than `==`; that's the original syntax, and it's a bit more portable.

If you're using bash, you can use the `[[` syntax, which doesn't require the quotes:

```
if [[ $var = $var1 ]]; then
```

Even then, it doesn't hurt to quote the variable reference, and adding quotes:

```
if [[ "$var" = "$var1" ]]; then
```

might save a future reader a moment trying to remember whether `[[` ... `]]` requires them.

Comment: Same error coming on greater than or less than operator. How to solve that as number comparison. if [ $var -gt $var1 ]

Answer (score 1):

Why all people want to use '==' instead of simple  '=' ? It is bad habit! It used only in [[ ]] expression. And in (( )) too. But you may use just = too! It work well in any case. If you use numbers, not strings use not parcing to strings and then compare like strings but compare numbers. like that

```
let -i i=5 # garantee that i is nubmber
test $i -eq 5 && echo "$i is equal 5" || echo "$i not equal 5"
```

It's match better and quicker. I'm expert in C/C++, Java, JavaScript. But if I use bash i never use '==' instead '='. Why you do so?

Comment: Well, there are more convincing arguments than _I'm an export in… Why you do so?_. See for example: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16110/59743. It tells you that `==` is an alias for `=`. `=` is a standard operator, whereas `==` is widely implemented but it's not POSIX: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html